# PHP and MySQL problem

Tags: php, mysql

How do I enter the `plus(+)` and `minus(-)` signs into a MySQL database and output them `+ -` as normal all while still using `mysqli_real_escape_string();` if there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: Can you describe the table you're inserting into, and how you're expecting to get the data back out?

Comment: Please share code, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 0):

What input/output are you actually getting? Whats the column type in the db for where you are trying to insert these?

Comment: I'm getting nothing for example an A- will produce nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) documentation, I do not think that the + and - characters are escaped. Only *NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, , ', ", and Control-Z* are escaped according to that page.

So I suppose you need to provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use `mysql_real_escape_string()` and set your charset for the table or row as `latin1` `utf8` might be a better choice though...

Could also play around with the different encodings urlencode() and such.

`//encode the update in case of & and other characters that will break twitter API
$update = '%E2%99%AB'.urlencode($update);`

`%E2%99%AB` creates the 'musical note symbol`

http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm